# Python - if statements and logical operators

Tags: python

I'm trying to do an if statements.
This working fine :

```
    with open(f, "r", encoding='mbcs') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:

            if 'codeclient' not in row[0]:
            
                
                print ("Not found") 
             else:
                print (row[0])
```

This one works too (see the difference)

```
    with open(f, "r", encoding='mbcs') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:

            
            if 'ANONYM' not in row[3] :
                
                print ("Not found") 
             else:
                print (row[0])
```

But I'd like to check the content of two conditions like this,but it does not work

```
    with open(f, "r", encoding='mbcs') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:

            if ('codeclient' not in row[0]) or ('ANONYM' not in row[3]) :
            
                
                print ("Not found") 
             else:
                print (row[0])
```

How could I check the 2 condition like this?

Many thanks

Comment: We have no idea what you expected this to do, or in what way it "does not work".  Perhaps the conditions need to be joined with `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: Use `and`.  If *both* are not found, print not found.  Or reverse the logic: `if 'codeclient in row[0] or 'ANONYM' in row[3]: print(row)`